# How to write a Synchronous function in Node using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, synchronous

1.How to write Promises Synchronously in Node so that I can get my desired output. I'm a newbie and would appreciate any help/suggestion.

```
// This is my core function

 var compareData = function(userIdArray) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var missingArray = new Array();
    userIdArray.forEach(function(id) {
      var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:6006/test1',
        headers:{
         'content-type': 'application/json' },
          body: { email: id },
          json: true
        };

      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        missingArray.push(body);
      });
    });
    resolve(missingArray);
  });
}


//I'm calling my function here

compareData(userIdArray)
.then(function(missingArray){
  console.log("The Body is: "+ missingArray);
});

/* I expect the console.log to print the missingArray with data from my POST call, 
but it prints an empty array. Can someone please tell me how to do this synchronously.
I'm pretty new to Node and finding it difficult to understand.*/
```

Comment: Promises are by definition async, you can*(do)* return the promise synchronously, but the promised value is **always** resolved async.

Comment: A Promise can't be synchronous, and synchronous code generally doesn't need a promise, so that makes little sense ?

Comment: You are resolving immediately with the `missingArray` var inside your promise. `request` is async, so your push will get called after the promise has been resolved, hence the empty array in then function. What you need is a `Promise.all` wrapped around requests for all userIds.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense. can you please suggest me a way to write this code in Node in such a way that I get my desired output(without Promise)?

Comment: Use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all.

Comment: @AkshendraPratap can you please actually re-write the code so that I can understand better? I tried Promise.all([compareData(userIDArray)]). But it didn't work

Comment: @adeneo  - Please suggest some alternative way to write the above code!

Comment: I guess that depends on what `request` is, it looks very asynchronous ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use external libraries as per @Thomas answer, you can use native Promises directly - and it's not too much more verbose

```
var compareData = function compareData(userIdArray) {
    return Promise.all(userIdArray.map(function (id) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var options = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:6006/test1',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: {
                    email: id
                },
                json: true
            };
            return request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                error ? reject(error) : resolve(body);
            });
        });
    }));
};

compareData(userIdArray)
.then(function (missingArray) {
    console.log("The Body is: " + missingArray);
});
```

Or, as this is node, which can handle more modern code:

```
var compareData = userIdArray => 
    Promise.all(userIdArray.map(id => 
        new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            request({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:6006/test1',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: {
                    email: id
                },
                json: true
            }, (error, response, body) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(body))
        )
    ));

compareData(userIdArray)
.then(missingArray => 
    console.log("The Body is: "+ missingArray)
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaromanda X . This is working fine, but it takes a lot of time to Return the Promise. I'm calling this compareData function inside my POST request and the request times out before this promise resolves and sends the response. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

with [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) and [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = require('request-promise');

var compareData = function(userIdArray) {
    //Promise.all(): 
        //takes an array of promises (and/or values), 
        //returns a promise of the resolved array
    return Promise.all( 
        userIdArray.map(function(id){
            return request({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:6006/test1',
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
                body: { email: id },
                json: true
            });
        }) 
    );
}
```

is there anything that needs further explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Without libraries, and assuming `request` doesn't already return a promise

```
var compareData = function(userIdArray) {
    return Promise.all(
        userIdArray.map(function(id) {
            var options = {
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'http://localhost:6006/test1',
                headers : { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
                body    : { email: id },
                json    : true
            };

            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                request(options, function(error, response, body) {
                    if (error) {
                        reject();
                    } else {
                        resolve(body);
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    );
}

compareData(userIdArray).then(function(missingArray) {
    console.log(missingArray);
});
```